# How to draw a path between two locations in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an android app in which I need to show the Google Map with the path drawn from source to destination.For Example I need to go from A to B there might be different routes but I need to draw only on a particular route.

This is what tried but it was not taking on any road it directly displaying a line from source to destination.

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity {
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
       /* googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                position(TutorialsPoint).title("My Location"));*/

        Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(17.4489224, 78.3483612), new LatLng(17.4831854, 77.9736794))
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.RED));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to create a Polyline object to specify the points, then you can set the Polyline object adding the Polyline options:

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Point A.
    .add(new LatLng(38.35, -123.0)); // Point B.

Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

To alter the shape of the polyline after it has been added, you can call Polyline.setPoints() and provide a new list of points for the polyline.

Comment: but I'm facing with another problem.When I'm loading map in normal activity the polyline is showing but when I'm showing the map in fragments its not showing the polyline.